# join two different list by id into one list

Tags: c#, list, join, merge, automapper

I've got two different list of two different objects. Then i got one list of a viewmodel that contains properties from both the objects and i want them to be joined into that list.

```
    //Product
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string unitMeasurement { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> minOrderQty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> packSize { get; set; }
    public string leadTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> generalAccessoryCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Weight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductType { get; set; }

    //ProductDescription
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string shortDescription { get; set; }
    public string detailDescription { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Rank { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }


     public class ProductResponse
{

    public string id { get; set; }

    //Product
    public string unitMeasurement { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> minOrderQty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> packSize { get; set; }
    public string leadTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> generalAccessoryCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Weight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductType { get; set; }

    //ProductDescription

    public string language { get; set; }
    public string shortDescription { get; set; }
    public string detailDescription { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Rank { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

So i just want to join a list of products and a list of productdescriptions into a list of productResponse. How can i do this? id of product and productdescription is the same so thats what i want to join them on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join them on id and then call `ToList`:

```
var productResponses = from p in products 
                       join pd in productDescriptions
                       on p.id equals pd.id
                       select new ProductResponse
                       { 
                          id = p.id,
                          language = pd.language,
                          // ...
                       }
var list = productResponses.ToList();
```

Comment: can i do that with lambda?

Comment: Yes of course, but i never use method syntax when it comes to join since it's so ugly. I will  never remember the parameters of [`Enumerable.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.100).aspx). This is not less efficient.

Comment: Do i need any special using references? Because it can't resolve join

Comment: My bad! I had tasks and not objects :) so it works :)